# when would webClient be called in webflux

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor

Reactor http operation is said to be cold, only run when subscribe or block is called. While in practice, it is said that when the mapped (or flatMapped, the value to the right of `->`) result is needed (or consumed), it would be called. Then I noticed that `log.info("{}", resultOfMap)` is not enough for its being called, but `function return from resultOfMap` is enough. Is there a logical reason for this, like *"what is the difference between log consumer and function return consumer from perspective of reactor"*, or are we playing *"hide-and-seek-and-eureka"*

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> postMethod(ServerRequest req) {
     req.bodyToMono(T.class)
            .map(t -> fromTtoD(t))
            .flatMap(d ->
                this.webClient
                    .post()
                    .uri(serverUri)
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(d))
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(E.class))
            .map(e -> log e and return e); // no! this would not make webClient called.
            .flatMap(e -> ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(e).build()) // yes! when return this 
}
```

Comment: On what basis is this conclusion made? `WebClient` creates a request to the source when the subscriber asks him to do it.

Comment: @MrBin "when the subscriber asks", there are many hiding subscribers. and the form does not have to be an obvious call for xxx.subscribe(). Then the question would be how to know who are the subscribers. Like in the PO, log is not the subscriber, but caller for `postMethod` is.

Comment: This is chained call to the first publisher. If you want to know *`who the lowest subscriber`* in chain, you may read the source code of `WebClient`. But it is not important to know.